# Weave third party dll with fody

Tags: c#, mono.cecil, fody

I would like to write a **Fody** plugin that will allow me to weave a third party dll.

Is it possible?

Reading the documentation and the source code from different plugins, I haven't found any way to do so.
It appears that fody only enables to weave the assembly that is referencing the plugin (using the ModuleDefinition property populated at build time).

As fody relies on Mono.Cecil I think it is technically possible, but it does not seems like my use case has been considered at all.

Tanks